# How to echo multiple values at once in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT $value1, $value2, $value3 from table where...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Is there a way to echo all 3 values, $value1, 2, 3 like this?

```
echo $row[$value1, $value2...];
```

What is the most effective way?

Comment: what are you doing with the values? are you using them on a web page or just outputting as a debug routine?

Comment: `echo $row[$value1], $row[$value2], $row[...];`

Comment: simple echo it or implode array....... why you want extra ordinary

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT($value1,'  ', $value2, '  ', $value3) AS item from table where...";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo $row->item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row[$value1] . $row[$value2]; //etc
    }
```